# Unable to start Active Directory Certificate Services afer migrating from 2003 to 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, migration, certificate-authority

I was in the process migrating our CA from a 2003 server to a 2012 R2 using this [guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/11/12/step-by-step-migrating-the-active-directory-certificate-service-from-windows-server-2003-to-2012-r2.aspx)

After a server restart the CA service will no longer start. I receive error 21: The device is not ready.

Is it worth fixing or would it be better, possibly my only solution, to start over? We don't use our CA for much. We have maybe 3 certificates pushed out from the CA. Something I'd like to work on as well...

**update**
I found the issue for my original problem. The original CA had the database installed on a separate volume opposed to the default location. I made the changes necessary in the registry to get the service started. My new problem is that when I click on Certificate Templates I'm greeted with the error: Template information could not be loaded. Element not found. :/

Comment: unfortunately, you chose the bad guide. Although, MS blogs are helpful, but not always. You should use official migration guide: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126170(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: It seemed helpful till I restarted the server. :( After that the service fails to start. I did go through the official guide trying to find a solution... I changed the permissions on AIA and CDP containers, etc... Didn't help. Looks like I'll be starting over.

Comment: Unfortunately, the StackExchange board format doesn't allow deep problem investigation, so I would suggest to post the question on TechNet forums (Windows Server Security forum directory) where we can delve into details. Hope this suggestion doesn't violate SE rules.

Comment: you might like to read the question posted by the OP - its not 2008 it's 2003 and it's not a migration its an upgrade - from the guide you linked to:  "In-place upgrades from Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2 or Windows Server 2003 R2 to Windows Server 2012 are not supported."

Comment: I think found the problem. The OLD CA didn't use the default locations for the install. The previous admin decided to create shares and put them there instead. Now I have to go through the registry and make the needed changes to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

Speaking personally, I would never upgrade a Windows system to a new release not even a desktop, migrating apps and data with the old configuration and a clean install of Windows is far more attractive in the long run, moreover there are almost 10 years between the Two systems and you will end up with a technical dept by upgrading - to put it in perspective this would be like upgrading Ubuntu 4.04 to 12.04 - if you have only signed 3 certificates then I would certainly do a clean install and take to opportunity to learn about root certificate authorities.

Comment: I definitely need to learn more about CA's. I guess now is the time.

Comment: The OP did not do an in-place upgrade of the OS, but rather a migration of the certificate services database and configuration. Did you even look at the process that he linked to?